# Count distinct values in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

This is the document structure in mongoDB

```
{ "_id" :ObjectId("9elesdf3lk3jppefll34d210"), "category" :"data1",product:'data'}
{ "_id" :ObjectId("9elesdf3lk3jppefll34d211"), "category" : "data2",product:'data'}
{ "_id" :ObjectId("9elesdf3lk3jppefll34d211"), "category" : "data1",product:'data' }
```

where `category` is indexed. I want to take a distinct count of the `category` field.

Currently I am using the following code to take the counts

```
db.collection.aggregate( 
   {$group : {_id : "$category"} }, 
   {$group: {_id:1, count: {$sum : 1 }}})
```

This query was giving me proper counts but my database is increasing day by day and the query is taking longer to execute. Is there some other methodology to take the counts in a faster way?

Comment: Have you tested the performance of `db.collection.distinct('category').length` as an alternative? `distinct` can use an index but `$group` cannot.

Comment: @JohnnyHK i have more than 10 million documents and growing..will it be able to procees so much data at once?

Comment: As long as it's able to use an index, sure. Roughly how many different categories are there?

Comment: @mikhilmohanan You should start accepting answers when you want help from SO users in the future, as there are 8 questions from you out there with answers but you didn't accept any of them ...

Comment: @DAXaholic Thankyou for oyur comment.ill take care of it in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already pointed out by [JohnnyHK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1259510/johnnyhk), use [db.collection.distinct](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/#db-collection-distinct) if possible as it provides the chance of [leveraging indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/#index-use)

So in your case `db.collection.distinct('category').length` should be pretty fast.
If you still suffer from performance issues then have a look at

```
db.collection.explain().distinct('category')
```

to see the execution plan of the query and take actions on it or provide it to this question so that we see whether your index is actually used.

Comment: i have executed the query..can you help me in identity which field specify that my index is being used or not

Comment: If you execute the ..explain().distinct('category') then you should see somewhere under queryPlanner.winningPlan a 'DISTINCT_SCAN' stage. If you see a 'COLLSCAN' stage then your index is not used.