# mongodb distinct sometimes uses index and sometimes doesn't

Tags: mongodb, distinct

I have collection `A` with a non-unique index over "`field1`".

If I run:

```
db.A.explain().distinct("field1")
```

I get:

```
"winningPlan" : {
    "stage" : "PROJECTION",
    ...
    "inputStage" : {
        "stage" : "DISTINCT_SCAN",
        "keyPattern" : {
            "field1" : 1.0
        },
    ...
}
```

Which suggests it'll use the index for the distinct call.

However, in collection `B` with a non-unique index on "`type2.key`", if I run:

```
db.B.explain().distinct("type2.key")
```

I get:

```
"winningPlan" : {
    "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
    "filter" : {
        "$and" : []
    },
    ...
}
```

which seems to mean it doesn't use the index.

Why can `distinct` use the index on collection `A` but not on collection `B`, and can I do something to force the use of the index?

Notes:

1. collection `B` is a lot bigger then collection `A`, is there a limit to the size of the index `distinct` can use?
2. I've read: [Count distinct values in mongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38548045/count-distinct-values-in-mongodb) and [MongoDB - distinct with query doesn't use indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36006208/mongodb-distinct-with-query-doesnt-use-indexes) they don't help to explain the difference in behavior I'm seeing.
3. Both collections are `sharded`
4. mongodb version is 3.2.12

**EXAMPLE DOCUMENT**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57d6c1cf691fa014e0615aa7"),
    "type1" : [ 
        {
            "key" : "key1",
            "field" : "value1",
        },
        {
            "key" : "key2",
            "field" : "value2",
        }
    ],
    "type2" : [ 
        {
            "key" : "key3",
            "field" : "value3",
        },
        {
            "key" : "key4",
            "field" : "value4",
        }
    ]
}
```

The index is on `type2.key`

Comment: Docs are very clear about it https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/#index-use : "When possible, it can use indexes.". Try `db.B.explain("allPlansExecution").distinct("obj.field2")` to see why it is not possible. `filters` part looks suspicious.  Do you have any query parameter there?

Comment: @AlexBlex I would claim that `When possible` is as vague as it gets... also, when trying the "allPlansExecution" mode, the explain never returns (it's a very big collection). Another thing I haven't mentioned is that this both collections are **sharded**, I'll add it to the question notes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rules when distinct index can be used are there https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v3.4/src/mongo/db/query/get_executor.cpp#L1104

Most important line for this particular case https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v3.4/src/mongo/db/query/get_executor.cpp#L1139 says:

> Skip multikey indices if we are projecting on a dotted field.

`"obj.field2"` is a dotted field, so index does not apply.

So basically, `distinct()` can use indexes only for root fields, not for array nor subdocuments.

Comment: thanks! that's a very good lead... but isn't `multikey index` an index over an array? if that's the case then my index isn't `multikey`.

Comment: Fair enough. It would be worth to add to the question. as well as mongodb version, and may be an example of documents in both collections to avoid further confusion.

Comment: mongodb version is 3.2.12, added to the question. come to think about it, the field before the dot in the index - `obj` - is an array of inner-documents, would that make my index `multikey`? I'll add an example document to the question

Comment: Yes. It is a multikey index. You can check it with `db.B.getIndexes()`

Comment: my understanding is that since this (4.1.10) fix https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13298 multikeys+dotted are supported, but in case of dotted field, mongo will use IXSCAN and cant a apply DISTINCT_SCAN